# Use file or S3 Path

Tags: java, rest, amazon-s3

Is it a good practice to pass the file to an API or pass s3 path? What would be the pros and cons of both the approaches?

We are calling an API which given a file/file path converts it into batches. I think security would be an issue while passing the file around , but in any case we are getting batches back(which would expose the data).

Comment: Your question is broad and vague, explain about your needs, current status, and problem.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to explain your requirements some more. We cannot really offer any advice on the small amount of information you have given. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)